# How jenkins can be use with Java 10 for selenium

Tags: java, jenkins

Can we use jenkins, if we are working on Java 10 version.

As according to their document, Jenkin is currently compatible up to Java 8.

So What should we have to use either Java 10 or Java 8 for Jenkins ?

Is their any other framework/tool, which is same as Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see that as per the official Jenkins blog,

> Starting from Jenkins 2.127, weekly releases can be launched with Java
>   10 and Java 11 (preview). Although there are some known compatibility
>   issues, the packages are ready for evaluation and exploratory testing.

You can find more information [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/17/running-jenkins-with-java10-11/)

Regarding,

> Is their any other framework/tool, which is same as Jenkins.

There are a lot of CI/CD vendors in the market. `GITLAB, Travis-CI, Circle-CI, go-CD` etc. to name a few.